# Loading online flash client into windows form in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, flash

I'm trying to load the game client for a flash game into a windows form using C# and the COM shockwave flash object. I manage to get the client to load in the form, but it does not seem that the client is set up properly, despite trying to mimic the vars given to the client as closely as possible.

For example, the flash client is loaded on the website using:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("flash/qplay.swf", "qplay", "760px", "592px", "11.0.0",false, {qplaycookie:"cookiehashgoeshere", gamefile:"qplay_era_20140214.png"}, {allowFullScreen:"true", allowFullScreenInteractive:"true", wmode:"direct", seamlesstabbing:"false", scale:"noscale",salign:"tl"},false);
```

I am trying to mirror this by loading the flash object in C# with the following arguments:

```
        flashClient.EmbedMovie = true;
        flashClient.SetVariable("qplaycookie", "cookiehashgoeshere");
        flashClient.SetVariable("gamefile", "qplay_era_20140214.png");
        flashClient.SeamlessTabbing = false;
        flashClient.SAlign = "t1";
        flashClient.AllowFullScreen = "true";
        flashClient.AllowFullScreenInteractive = "true";
        flashClient.WMode = "direct";
        flashClient.LoadMovie(0, "http://era.graalonline.com/flash/qplay.swf");
        flashClient.Play();
```

To no effect. The movie loads into the form flash object, but remains dormant at the first loading screen, as if it hasn't been given the aforementioned variables or initialized in some way. I've pored through the javascript libs on the website the client is hosted on (era.graalonline.com) and haven't found anything that seems to interact with the client proper to supply it with any information beyond what is referenced in the embedSWF call.

I've also tried altering the gamefile variable to have a proper URI path to the website the game client is hosted on, to no success.

I'm at a loss. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the correct answer was to use the FlashVars line and load the gamefile path remotely. Pretty simple mistake.

```
flashClient.FlashVars = "cookiehashgoeshere&gamefile=http://era.graalonline.com/qplay_era_20140214.png";
```

Hope this is of any use to anyone else dabbling around with similar things.